# XAML designer errors in VS2015

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Our team is porting an existing Universal windows application (8.1) to Windows 10. After installation of VS 2015 we faced with lots of weird problems in xaml editor. For example:

`Ivalid type: expected type is 'DataTemplate', actual type is 'DataTemlate'.`
or `'Ivalid style target type: expected type is 'ProgressRing', actual type is 'ProgressRing'.`

Similar errors are everywhere in XAML files. Please, see some screenshots attached.

[image: Weird XAML error.]
[image]

Has anyone faced with similar issues? At runtime everything works fine, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be related to Resharper. I do have the same problem but only if Resharper is enabled.

If you are using Resharper, try suspending it, then re-open the designer and see if you still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> "'DataTemplate', actual type is 'DataTemlate'"

Seems like a spelling error, although it's odd that this still compiles fine, because it should not be able to find this type if it is spelled incorrectly.